# Installing Windows 10 and save data. Should I remove system reserved/recovery partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, partitioning

if I want to reinstall Windows, but save the data more than 80GB (photos, documents, etc.) on one of the partition (disk E:/), what do I need to format and delete? Can I format all disks except for which there is an important information? And **is it possible to remove any system partitions, recovery partitions**, etc. from the old Windows? Or it's not desirable?

Before was installed Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple disks available, you can format and delete pretty much whatever you want as long as it doesn't contain your active system files (your primary partition).

[Open Disk Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management) on your computer - it will give you an overview of your disks and their partitions. If you have more than one disk, you can [create a new partition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323442/how-to-use-the-disk-management-snap-in-to-manage-basic-and-dynamic-dis#4) or [volume](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323442/how-to-use-the-disk-management-snap-in-to-manage-basic-and-dynamic-dis#10) where you can back your data up to.

My preferred method of installing Windows 10 is via a USB drive. I format a small portion of the drive and [load it with the installation media](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15088/windows-10-create-installation-media), then I usually format the remaining space on the USB stick for storage (may contain other installation files, drivers, executables etc. if you need your initial setup to be offline).

Once you have your media ready, you can boot from your USB and it will walk you through the [process of installing Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive). If you feel unsure about deleting the wrong partitions, I recommend backing up all of your data to one disk and unplugging that disk before you do anything else - that way you can't really mess up anything.

To answer your **bolded question:** during the installation I usually delete all of the disk partitions that *aren't* my USB drive so I have a clean image. There are tons of guides and videos online if you have specific questions or are feeling apprehensive.

**Edit based on new information from comments!:**
You don't need multiple disks to have a backup partition - I just recommend naming your backup partition (my go-to is "Storage") so you can easily identify which partition is which when Windows is asking you where you want it to install (after booting from your installation media) - the idea being you DO NOT delete or install Windows over your backup partition.

Comment: So, I can delete them? OS creates new system partitions?

Comment: Yes, if you are installing a fresh OS you can delete them. I wouldn't worry about deleting them prior to the installation - you will have the option to do so during it.

Comment: I can't make clean install (as u, by deletin all disks) and cant make backup :)

Comment: not sure I follow... do you have multiple disks? or just multiple partitions/volumes on one disk?

Comment: Oh, no, I don't have multiple disks. I have multiple partitions on one disk. So I have one HDD and 3 partitions (C, D, E) as usual. And I need to save files on E:/ disk (partition).

Comment: ah ok - it's basically the same thing, you'll just leave your `E:` partition alone. I recommend naming your `E:` partition so when you're doing your Windows installation you'll be able to see exactly which one it is; then you can delete the other two, or just your primary partition - which will make them show up as "unallocated space" - which you will then install Windows on.

Comment: So, it needed to delete them not format? And what about sys reserved partitions? May I delete them too?

Comment: You just delete them (sys reserved included) during the installation process and then format over them; formatting a partition essentially "deletes" everything on it anyway. You don't need to delete or format anything prior to booting from your installation media - unless it's to prepare/name your storage/backup partition.

Comment: Oh.. Ok, ty a lot!

Comment: it's no problem; it all sounds wayyyyy more complicated than it actual is.